# How to run a server side function on html form submit

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created an html form to allow users to submit their emails to spreadsheet tab "Emails"

In the spreadsheet I created another tab "Sort Emails" to sort the results of "Emails" tab in a reverse order so while people submit their emails, I have the new submitted email in Sort Emails B2.

The problem is: Now I am trying to automatically send an email to new submitted email on-Submit, i.e once a new user submits the form, the script sends an email to the user's email that is supposed to be located in Sort Emails B2. Any help please. Thanks in advance!

**Please note when I run the function SendEmail manually from the sheet script editor, it does the job but my question is about running the function automatically on form submit**

*I'm not much experienced but I think we need a trigger to run the SendEmail function automatically whenever a new row is added to the sheet and of course I tried the current project's triggers in the script editor (both onEdit and onChange) but no luck (I don't understand why??)*

This is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>

<form name="Subscribe" id="Subscribe" action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/ScriptKey/exec" method="POST" onsubmit="myFunction()">
Form Inputs ..
</form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  google.script.run.SendEmail();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is my gs file:

```
function doGet() {
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Form.html')
        .evaluate() // evaluate MUST come before setting the Sandbox mode
        .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}

var sheetName = 'Emails'
var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()


function doPost (e) {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)
  
  try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

    var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'Timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])
    var y = sheet.getLastRow();
    var x = sheet.getRange(y,2).getValues();

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'Central Says': 'Successfully subscribed', 'Email': x }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}

function SendEmail() {
var e = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sort Emails").getRange("B2").getValues();
var m = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Template").getRange("A1").getValues();
var subject = 'Welcome ..';
MailApp.sendEmail(e, subject, m);
}
```

Comment: Can you share the full code? Do you have anything on doGet / doPost? Also have you checked how Client-Side API works? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run

Comment: I updated the question with the full gs code. thanks

Comment: Since you have already the doPost(e) set-up, why is that you are not sending the email at the end of the doPost(e) function? It is already a trigger and ,actually, the one you need to use because [OnEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) runs when a **user** changes something in a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to change the `getActiveSpreadsheet()` for `openById("SPREADSHEET ID")` and then you have two options:

You keep the `SendEmail()` function:

```
function SendEmail() {
  var e = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEET ID").getSheetByName("Sort Emails").getRange("B2").getValue();
  var m = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEET ID").getSheetByName("Template").getRange("A1").getValue();
  var subject = 'Welcome ..';
  MailApp.sendEmail(e, subject, m);
}
```

Or do it everything inside the `doPost` and delete the call to the `SendEmail()` function in the HTML:

```
function doPost (e) {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {

    var e = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEET ID").getSheetByName("Sort Emails").getRange("B2").getValue();
    var m = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEET ID").getSheetByName("Template").getRange("A1").getValue();
    var subject = 'Welcome ..';
    MailApp.sendEmail(e, subject, m);

    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

    var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'Timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])
    var y = sheet.getLastRow();
    var x = sheet.getRange(y,2).getValues();

    return ContentService
    .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'Central Says': 'Successfully subscribed', 'Email' : x}))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)  
  }
  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
    .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The correct way to do that is making a request to a server side application that you you should create to handle this server side stuffs, an API.
You can create this API very easily work frameworks like [Express.js](https://expressjs.com/)
or [Koa.js](https://koajs.com/)

Then in your server side you would handle like this:

```
... // Initializing stuffs
app.post('/sendEmail/:email', function(req, res, next) {
    const userEmail = req.params.email;
    try {
        google.script.run.SendEmail(userEmail);
        res.json({ message: 'success' });
    } catch (err) {
        res
          .status(400)
          .json({ message: 'failure' + err.message })
    }
});
```

Comment: `const` & arrow functions aren't supported in Google Apps Script - I don't think this answer would work for OP.

Comment: So it's just not needed to put async and await, I'll take those off

Comment: The code you posted runs on the browser side and not the server side right?